# Comparing HTML Option value with php variable

Tags: php

I've written this piece of code:

```
<select name="account_type" id="account" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="Asset">Asset</option>
    <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
    <option value="Capital">Capital</option>
    <option value="Cash" <?php if($_POST['Cash'] == $ledger_account){?> selected <?php }?>>Cash</option>
    <option value="Expense">Expense</option>
    <option value="Income">Income</option>
    <option value="Liability">Liability</option>
    <option value="Creditors">S. Creditors</option>
</select>
```

I got a value from different page, which is stored in $ledger_account. However, I want to see an option (for example, Cash) to be selected here when the page loaded if the option value matches with $ledger_account value. Please help me to identify what I've done wrong here.

Comment: your code seems correct, update your complete code

Comment: it sounds like you just want `if('Cash' == $ledger_account)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Sean as I didn't know, 'Cash' is comparable with $ledger_account.

Comment: Comparing the values still not outputting as selected. @Sean

Comment: Have you verified the actual value of `$ledger_account`? You say that you got the value from a different page. Try echoing out `$ledger_account` and seeing if its value is valid.

Comment: Yes it's verified. The $ledger_account variable is working perfectly in other places. @Sean

Comment: is it possible that there is unseen whitespace? You could try `if('Cash' == trim($ledger_account))`

Comment: No possibility because I am particularly trying with the value 'Cash', which is a one word value. @Sean

Answer (score 0):

Your code are correct. but it's give some error..

then try to somting like this...

```
 <option value="Cash" <?php if($_POST['Cash'] == $ledger_account){ ?> selected="selected" <?php }?> >Case</option>
```

I am not sure but i think this useful for you

Comment: Tried. But the option is not selected after page load.

Comment: Okay.. Please explain how can get vakue of  $ledger_account and also $_POST['Cash'].... in html template

Comment: I think your condition is getting always false... So it's not selected...

Comment: So, First print both value in your html template... and check which value given after load page..

Comment: You mean outputting like this? echo $_POST['Cash']
What should be output of it?

Comment: yes in your html template for both... use this code <?php  echo $_POST['Cash'];  ?>

Comment: Its not outputting anything.

Comment: Yah... Means your condition always geting 'false' So, it's not displaying Selected Option...